# How to distribute points evenly on a circle in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create 10 points distributed on a circle, just like a watch but with 10 numbers instead of 12. and also be able to use the dots/points to plot lines between them.
This is the code I used to create a circle but can't figure out how to make them 10 points, and also how to use the points' coordinates in my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# T = testing
# myList = testing.digitcounter(18, 20)

def circle_points(r, n):
    circles = []
    for r, n in zip(r, n):
        t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
        x = r * np.cos(t)
        y = r * np.sin(t)
        circles.append(np.c_[x, y])
    return circles

r = [0.15]
n = [15]
circles = circle_points(r, n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for circle in circles:
    ax.scatter(circle[:, 0], circle[:, 1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=false)` to spread `n` points evenly over a circle.  Default `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=true)` puts the last point at the same angle as the first.

Comment: Thank you, this works for spreading n points evenly on a circle, but how can I plot lines between these points?

Comment: How do you want to connect them? Like an n-gon? Or an n-pointed star? Or ...? For an n-gon you could try to create `n+1` points (`np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n+1, endpoint=True)`) and then call `ax.plot(circle[:, 0], circle[:, 1])`.  `n+1` points with the first and the last coinciding are needed to close the n-gon.

Comment: say I have a list/dic of random digits (0 to 9), each digit is associated with a point (x,y) from the 10 points I drew, I want to connect every 2 subsequent points "digits" according to their appearance in the list. so basically I want to connect the dots randomly between each other, so I must be able to use their x,y coordinates in my code in order to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10, endpoint=False)`, you can create 10 angles equally distributed over a circle.  The default `endpoint=True` would have the first and last angle coincide.  To have the first point at the top, and going clockwise, interchange `cos` and `sin` in the formula.

To plot a continuous line between digits, you could use `ax.plot(circle[digits, 0], circle[digits, 1])`, with `digits` a numpy array of integers between 0 and 1. Note that this will contain a line of zero length when two subsequent digits would be equal.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def circle_points(r, n):
    circles = []
    for r, n in zip(r, n):
        t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n, endpoint=False)
        x = r * np.sin(t)
        y = r * np.cos(t)
        circles.append(np.c_[x, y])
    return circles

digits = np.random.randint(0, 10, 7)  # 7 random digits between 0 and 9
circle10 = circle_points([0.15], [10])[0] # 10 points on a circle
circle10 = circle10[(np.arange(10) - 3) % 10, :] # with 3 at the top

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(circle10[:, 0], circle10[:, 1], color='crimson')
ax.plot(circle10[digits, 0], circle10[digits, 1], color='dodgerblue', lw=3)
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(circle10):
    ax.text(x * 1.1, y * 1.1, i, ha='center', va='center', color='crimson')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.margins(x=0.1, y=0.1) # extra margins, because the text isn't taken into account for the default margins
ax.set_title("".join([f'{d}' for d in digits]), size=16)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Similarly, a 17-pointed star could be drawn with:

```py
N = 17
circle = circle_points([0.15], [N])[0]
for i in range(N):
    ax.plot([circle[i, 0], circle[(i + 6) % N, 0]],
            [circle[i, 1], circle[(i + 6) % N, 1]], 
            color='dodgerblue', lw=3)
```

[image: 17-pointed star]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works brilliantly. but one more question if I may, what if I wanted to have the circle's points start at a number other than 0, for example, I want 3 to be at the 12 o'clock point and then the rest follow as usual from 4 up and back to 2, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I added `circle10 = circle10[(np.arange(10) - 3) % 10, :]` to shift the points to have 3 at the top